# What is the meaning of the *(volatile void**) in c?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, volatile, double-pointer

I was working on the "QNX RTOS" in which i came across the following line can anyone please help me to understand?

```
*(volatile  void **) kernel_data = (void *) & _mqx_version_number;
```

Regards,
Omkar Dixit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(volatile  void **)kernel_data` --> cast `kernel_data` to pointer to pointer of type volatile void.

Now, `kernel_data` is a pointer to pointer (`volatile void**`)
`*kernel_data` is pointer of type `volatile void*`

`*(volatile  void **) kernel_data = (void *) & _mqx_version_number;`

So, here, we are type casting `kernel_data` to type `volatile  void **` and then dereferencing it.

Comment: Okay I will search examples of the same. Thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: Actually, its was a vendor file in which i found the same line and i haven't got any syntax error for the same.

Comment: @OmkarDixit  Sorry, you will not get any syntax error.

Comment: `*kernel_data` means dereferencing .

Comment: Okay okay now i got it!